# Laravel (exit in controller)

Tags: php, laravel

Назрел один вопрос: хорошая ли это практика, останавливать выполнение каких либо действий методом `exit()` (будь это контроллер, планировщик задач, работы и тд), Вместо того чтобы прудить условия и усложнять этим логику и читаемость кода.

Жду ваших мнений по этому поводу

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В фреймворках типа laravel - это плохая практика. В таких фреймворках используются события и некоторые действия откладывают выполнение на момент после отдачи буфера страницы. Например логирование, события действий с бд, очереди отправки сообщений и многое другое. `exit()` в контроллере оборвет выполнение и отдаст ошибку 500. В некоторых случаях может привести к некорректному состоянию данных